# display messages from the javascript console

Tags: javascript, logging, console

how would I use javascript to loop through the messages in the javascript console and display them to a user, for example adding them line by line to a container element like a `div`.

I understand how to add messages to the console with `console.log` but my question is, is there any way to then retrieve messages that have been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this the idea is to intercept anything being sent to the console. Here is a cross browser solution.

```
   function takeOverConsole(){
        var console = window.console
        if (!console) return
        function intercept(method){
            var original = console[method]
            console[method] = function(){
                var message = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).join(' ')
                // do sneaky stuff
                if (original.call){
                    // Do this for normal browsers
                    original.call(console, message)
                }else{
                    // Do this for IE
                    original(message)
                }
            }
        }
        var methods = ['log', 'warn', 'error']
        for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++)
            intercept(methods[i])
    }
```

Found this from [taking-over-console-log/](http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/)

Here I call the the function, and do a simple log "hey". It will interecept it and I will alert the intercepted message. http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/zetcpm1a/

**To explain how this function works:**

1. We declare a variable `console` with the actual console. If the `console` is `undefined` we just stop right away and leave the function.
2. We declare `var methods = ['log', 'warn', 'error']` for the different console message types
3. We loop through the methods and call the `intercept` function and send the `console type` (string: 'log', 'warn', etc).
4. Intercept function simply applies a listener~ to that type of console message. In our case we are applying a listener to log, warn and error.
5. We retrieve the message and put it in the message variable.
6. Since we intercepted the message, it won't be shown in the console, so we go ahead and original.call() or original() to add it to the console.

Comment: Can you give the above solution as a working example?

Comment: i can't really understand the above function with my current level of javascript knowledge, however the idea of intercepting when i'm doing `console.log(something)` and moving that data somewhere else that can be read is very helpful. i might go down that path instead.

Comment: @SenyaPeterCullen just check the jsfiddle. The message you want is located in the message variable.

Comment: thank you for the update. i understand the function now! very nice :)