# Way to save console.count() as an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I am trying to divide 1 by the console.count() every time it is used. However, this code does not work.

```
   var counter = console.count();
    console.log(1/counter);
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this? I tried doing parseInt but no luck.

Comment: You might be using `console.count()` incorrectly (at least in Chrome): https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolecountlabel

Comment: `console.count()` does not return anything - the point is to log the count to the console. If you need a counter for your logic, build it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Way to save console.count() as an integer?

No. `console.count()` does not return anything, it directly prints to the console, just like `console.log()`.

---

Simple implementation of `console.count`:

```js
var count = (function() {
  var counter = {};
  return function(v) {
    return (counter[v] = (counter[v] || 0) + 1);
  }
}());

console.log('foo', count('foo'));
console.log('foo', count('foo'));
console.log('bar', count('bar'));
```

Comment: Is there anyway to mimic a way to save console.count() as an integer?

Comment: *"to mimic a way to save"* That doesn't seem to make sense. But if you mean to replicate `console.count`'s logic, sure that's possible (and very easy).

Comment: Is there a way where I can update the count every time a variable is updated from a different function?

Comment: You cannot intercept variable assignments, if that's what you mean. I also don't see how this is related to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that intercepts messages sent to the console.

```
var counter = 0;
function takeOverConsole(){
        var console = window.console
        if (!console) return
        function intercept(method){
            var original = console[method]
            console[method] = function(){
                var message = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).join(' ')
                // do sneaky stuff
                if (original.call){
                    // Do this for normal browsers
                    original.call(console, message)
                }else{
                    // Do this for IE
                    original(message)
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        var methods = ['log', 'warn', 'error', 'count']
        for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++)
            intercept(methods[i])
    }
```

To take Felix King's answer a bit further. Here is a more accurate way to intercept and count anything being sent to the console.

You can customize the function a bit and add any methods you want to track and count.

[All console methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)

I talk about it more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821484/display-messages-from-the-javascript-console/28821587#28821587)